# Store user-upload file to specified local folder

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to create an app where User A uploads a file to server and User B can download it to a local folder.
I am first implementing the actions of uploading the file, and then immediately store that file to my own specified folder (since I am the sole User here). This is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose csv File',
              accept=c('text/csv'))
)

server <- function(input , output){
    rootDir <- 'C:/RShiny/Dir'  
    inFile <- reactive({input$file1})

    file.copy(inFile()$datapath,
               file.path(rootDir, inFile()$name, fsep = .Platform$file.sep))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

However, I keep receiving this error message:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  53: stop
  52: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  51: getCurrentContext
  50: .dependents$register
  49: inFile
  47: server [C:\RShiny\.../app.R#12]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

And the app just closes right away. Not sure what it means and how to fix it. If someone could help explaining?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose csv File',
              accept=c('text/csv'))
)

server <- function(input , output){
    rootDir <- 'C:/RShiny/Dir'  
    inFile <- reactive({input$file1})

    observe({
        file.copy(inFile()$datapath,
              file.path(rootDir, inFile()$name, fsep = .Platform$file.sep))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

You need to put the `file.copy()` code in an `observe` ("a reactive expression or observer").

Comment: You can read up more on reactivity in shiny here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html and elsewhere online.